# Efficient and quick way to rasterize very large polygon (20GB)

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, rasterization

I´m currently working on a large (> 20 GB) vectorized dataset (Geopackage format) holding land cover classification information for an entire country. I´m looking for an efficient and quick way to run the rasterization process.
Currently I'm using `Rasterize (vector to raster)` from QGIS, but it's extremely slow. Since the data should match with other raster-data it's not an option to simplify the data first.

I have also tried running ArcGIS Pro, but it doesn't work well with Geopackage and performance is even worse.

Can you recommend a faster processes to achieve the rasterization?

Below examples of expected Input (Vector) and Output (Raster)

[image: Input example with Vector format (.gpkg)]

[image: Output example with Raster format (.tif)]

Comment: Please decide upon a single software that you wish to ask about in this particular question.  That way you can describe what you've tried with it and where you're stuck.

Comment: The more you can simplify the vector geometry before you rasterize, the faster the rasterization will go. Also what spatial resolution are you using for the raster?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. The vector is originated from a 10x10m raster, with added information in the poligonised version. What tools would you consider for simplifying the geometry without the loss of information then?

Comment: What is the resolution (e.g. 16000x12000 pixels) of the final image?

Comment: Hi @BERA and @bugmenot123; I checked with my colleague: we have not postgresql+postgis in place for this task. About the resolution: I only know it's derived from 10m Sentinel imagery and roughly 200.000 km² in size, I believe

Comment: Maybe you run out of memory. I would try splitting the vector dataset into smaller pieces then process each piece individually. Then merge the output rasters into one. You can for example [create a grid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid) covering the vector dataset, then intersect. And [split](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) the output by grid id.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @BERA. In the next procedures we will take them into account. QGIS managed to conclude the processing, but it took one week overall without crashes.